# Elevation profile that takes into account earth's curvature

Tags: google-earth, elevation

My class doing some experiments with push to talk radios and line of sight. Google Earth Pro has an option that displays the elevation profile between two points (really cool btw), but I'd really love to see this profile in relation to the curvature of the earth so we can work out if two points can communicate via line of sight radio. Is there an option in Google Earth - or are there any free mapping tools out there - that can do this?

[image: Please make this curve]

Comment: You need a DEM and for example https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_viewshed.html. Notice that before GDAL 3.4 the default value of Curvature Coeff was 0 (=flat Earth).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Earth Pro supports elevation profiles with earth curvature, so you'll have to find another tool for that.  One free mapping tool I'm aware of that does line of sight calculations including terrain and earth curvature is from the internet device company Ubiquiti ([ui.com](https://www.ui.com/)).  They have a point to point link simulation tool called Link: https://link.ui.com/#

With that you can do detailed RF studies that even take into account the antenna pattern and gain of their specific devices.  You should be able to approximate a basic radio, and can generate a profile like in the screenshot below, which shows a link from San Francisco's Point Lobos out to the Faralon Islands. There is direct line of sight, just barely, but the fresnel zone intersects the ocean due to earth's curvature, so this link would be better served from a higher point in SF.

[image: Ubiquiti Link example screenshot]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!

Comment: Sure thing, happy to help.  If you can mark the question as answered, I would appreciate it.